# Winform Cefsharp: Can't clear cache directory

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I'm using `CefSharp` in my `WinForm` project.
I wan't to clear the cache directory in real time:

```
if (browser != null)
{
    BrowserPanel.Controls.Remove(browser);
    browser = null;
}

String cachePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + @"\TelegramParser\Users\" + userName;
if (Directory.Exists(cachePath))
{
    Directory.Delete(cachePath, true);
}
```

But I always get an error that it is not possible to delete this directory.

This is how I declare the browser:

```
String cachePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + @"\TelegramParser\Users\" + userName;

if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(cachePath))
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(cachePath);
} 

var requestContextSettings = new RequestContextSettings { CachePath = cachePath };

if (browser != null && BrowserPanel.Controls.Contains(browser))
    BrowserPanel.Controls.Remove(browser);

browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
browser.RequestContext = new RequestContext(requestContextSettings, new CustomRequestContextHandler());
browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

JsDialogHandler js1 = new JsDialogHandler();
browser.JsDialogHandler = js1;

BrowserPanel.Controls.Add(browser);
browser.Load("https://google.com/");
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I'm speculating but you may need to call Cef.Shutdown to release the lock on the directory before trying to delete it. Otherwise you maybe try to clear before creating any browser or calling Cef.Initialize.

Comment: @jake.lange I want to do it in real time, also the cache path s specific for this browser only and not for other

Comment: hmm I see. The browser object is disposable and the code you posted doesn't call dispose, not sure if that would help or not.

Comment: @jake.lange This method also didn't help. Still get msg that it's not possible to delete the cache directory

Comment: Unfortunately there is no option for deleting the `Cache` whilst the app is running. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1234
You can delete cookies.

Answer (score 1):

As of 85.4 it is  possible to delete cache of a running CefSharp browser using [DevToolsClient](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3165) and [Network.ClearBrowserChache](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-clearBrowserCache). As mentioned on [General Usage wiki of CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#need-to-knowlimitations).

```
private async Task ClearCache(object sender)
{
    using (var devToolsClient = Browser.GetDevToolsClient())
    {
        var response = await devToolsClient.Network.ClearBrowserCacheAsync();
    }
}
```

Note: this will not deleted the entire folder, it will however clear cached objects.

Comment: Even when calling the ClearBrowserCacheAsync and ClearBrowserCookiesAsync methods, the previous session's state remains.

Comment: @Mort The question was about clearing cache directory not about session state.